# Error with generating JasperPrint in the client side

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jnlp

I am using JNLP which fetches my jar files to client.
When I run the application, I am getting the error: `JasperPrint(NullPointerException)`.

I can figure out the cause partially. It is because `JasperPrint` instance cannot be stored on client side due to access permission.

Is there a way to generate `JasperPrint` on the client side?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:151)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:215)
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:523)
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:283)
 at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:236)
 at ....

Comment: jasperPrint = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), jrrs);
In the above stmt, its throwing an exception. But the pgm works fine when normally launched without jnlp webstart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved...
I forgot to sign the jar resources.